# read .sas source code on osx without installing sas?

Tags: r, sas

Plain and simple: is there a way to read (not run) .sas files on osx in order to rewrite old SAS programs in another language, e.g. R? Note I do not refer to reading sas data files – I know there are several ways, I am just interested in reading old SAS code.

Comment: Are source files in some kind of binary format? If not, you can use any text editor to read the code.

Comment: You could probably open them in R's editor, but you might have to change the filter on the file selection box from `*.R` to `*.*` in order to list them. That's if R/Mac is anything like R/Windows. Or use another text editor, as suggested...

Comment: sorry for the noise everybody... I realize they are not binary and can be read by textwrangler and probably most other editors. I don't know what made me think it doesn't work. Maybe there are multiple kind of .sas files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.sas files containing SAS code should just be a text file.  You can use any text editor that you like to open and modify these files.  Since the system probably doesn't have .sas files associated with any particular program you can either use the "Open with" option when "right-clicking" on the file or you could open the editor first and then open the file from within the editor.

Comment: +1 you're right indeed. Really can't see why I had problems opening these files in the past...

Comment: @MattBannert it's possible you were seeing the binary `sas7bdat` format in the past...

Comment: @MichaelChirico Your comment brought me back to this question. Which in turn surprised me that I answered a question tagged not only with SAS but with OSX as well. Apparently 2012 was different times for me...

Comment: I would have been on windows when you wrote this answer, come to think of it! and speaking of which... osx tag removed as it doesn't seem crucial

Answer (score 2):

TextEdit will work. Another editor that I like is Komodo Edit.